# the_widget() - filter only one instance

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, widgets, sidebar

If I have 3 widget instances like:

```
the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Cart', array( 'title' => 'Cart 1' ) );
the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Cart', array( 'title' => 'Cart 2' ) );
+ the same widget assigned to a sidebar in Appearance > Widgets
```

then how would I edit only one instance using a filter?

```
function wpse_123_woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity( $html_output, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    return '<span class="quantity">1234</span>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', 'wpse_123_woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
```

What have I tried:

1. `add_action( 'the_widget', 'my_filter_function', 10, 3 );` doesn't have access to the instance ID, it's pre-render hook.
2. `add_filter('widget_display_callback', 'wpse_123_widget_display_callback', 10, 3);` doesn't work for `the_widget()` but works for the sidebar.

Comment: Which one? How do you want to recognize the one widget you want to modify?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out: how to get the widget's instance ID :) I think I just found the answer `the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Cart', array( 'title' => 'Cart 2', 'some-arbitrary-property' => 1234 ) );`. I think I can set any arbitrary property and use `add_action( 'the_widget', 'my_filter_function', 10, 3 );` after all. So, I think this is solved. (I just didn't realize that it will allow me to pass non-official properties too.)